# Comparing two uneven lists for differences

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I am trying to compare two columns for differences between them using conditional formatting and the COUNTIF function. However, I notice that it's not case sensitive and hence I am not getting the accurate differences I expected. Could anyone provide a more accurate way for me to find the values in only one list and not the other and filter out appropriately? Thanks.

Edits. Sample data and expected result.

List 1: AS12346 AS12347 005234ES Apple Banana ABCDE

List 2: AS12346 005234ES banana abcde

Expected Result (taking case sensitivity into consideration): AS12347 Apple banana ABCDE

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: And what you have already tried, as well.

Comment: @Atzmon I have update my question to include sample data and expected result as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EXACT function that is case sensitive.
Formula for conditional formatting for respective cells in List 1 can be

```
=ISNA(MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A2,$B$2:$B$7),0))
```

Is this example List-1 is at A2:A7 & List-2 at B2:B7. In this example I have highlighted difference in light yellow. Note that this compares only List-1 with List-2 and not vice versa.

[image]

If you wish to Filer Out the list you can use a Helper Column say Column C. Put the below Array formula in Column C and Filter out on #N/A

```
{=MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A2,$B$2:$B$7),0)}
```

You need to Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER in the formula bar after you complete the formula editing to get proper Array Formula.

[image]